# laravel livewire actions not calling method when having more than one livewire action in compoent's view

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have two livewire wire:click action in component's view. The first action does work fine but second doesn't.

```
<button wire:click="test">Test</button>
<button wire:click="add">Add</button>
```

Component class look like this:

```
public function test() {
  dd("test");
}
public function add() {
  dd("add");
}
```

So when i click on test button it shows test string but add button doesn't show add string. But if i remove/comment test button, second button will work fine. Why is that So?

Answer (score 7):

I expect that you have forgotten to wrap both buttons in a parent element in your view:

```
<div>
    <button wire:click="test">Test</button>
    <button wire:click="add">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats great to hear @MilanBudhathoki, please make sure to mark my answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: @DanHarrin Thank you so much, I can't belive I did this mistake and it takes me hours trying to fix it. Thanks again 